# Invertir orden de div

Tags: html, css3

si tengo 2 div de la siguiente forma

```
<div class="uno"></div>
<div class="dos"></div>
```

como hago para invertirlos con css?, sin usar position:absolute.
que quede así

```
<div class="dos"></div>
<div class="uno"></div>
```

se puede?

Comment: Hay varias formas, lo más facil es con flexbox. Necesitas un contenedor para los div con `display:flex` y luego puedes usar la propiedad `order` para cambiar el orden en que se muestran

Comment: Lo más limpio sería utilizar la propiedad `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`, de otra manera tendrás que añadir `order` a cada elemento que quieras agregar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

la única forma de darles orden con css es usando la propiedad flex para el contenedor de estos elementos

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex > * {
  order: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 2px;
}

.uno {
 order: 1;
}

.dos {
 order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="uno">elemento A</div>
  <div class="dos">elemento B</div>
  <div>elemento C</div>
</div>
```

te dejo un vínculo con un tutorial de flex

[Tutorial Flex CSS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: no es la única aunque si la más fácil y seguramente la mejor. De hecho yo propuse una alternativa en una pregunta similar en SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008866/4994625

Comment: ciertamente no es la única manera, pero las soluciones alternativas son aquellas que juegan con las propiedades de css para llegar a esos resultados lo que lleva a tener hojas de estilos un poco difíciles de leer e innecesariamente largas, cuando llegó flexbox fue para solucionar este tipo de problemas triviales y darle un orden. La solución "oficial" es flexbox y se insta a dejar de usar las soluciones alternativas

Comment: Exactamente @LPZadkiel, repetición de código, redundancias y demás trivialidades solo ensucian código. La mejor alternativa en mi opinión sería utilizar la propiedad `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`, de otra manera tendrás que añadir `order` a cada elemento que quieras agregar.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo la propiedad `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`, puesto que hace el contenido más dinámico, si he entendido bien el uso que quieres hacer del comportamiento, como el orden de creciente a decreciente, comentarios más recientes primero, etcétera. De la otra manera tendrás que ir agregando el orden a cada elemento que creas y es un fastidio, ya que cuando tienes cientos de líneas de código, cuanto más simple sea mejor.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse
}

.container > * { width: 100% }

.foo { background-color: #ff3b30 }

.bar { background-color: #4cd964 }

.baz { background-color: #007aff }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
  <div class="baz">baz</div>
</div>
```