# ¿Cómo ordenar el posicionamiento de div en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando ordenar div dependiendo de lo que venga de la url, me explico,

http://127.0.0.1:5500/index2.html?group=equipos&card=pro

tengo el grupo "equipos" y tengo la card que empiece por "pro"

entonces lo que debería hacer es ordenar las carde dependiendo que coloque en la url, osea si es "pro" que quede primero la card "pro", si busco por ultra me deja primero la card "ultra".

```
<div class="container-equipos" id="equipos">
    <div class="equipos" data-equipo="1">
        <img src="./img/telefono.png" alt="">
        <p>Plan Libre Pro</p>
    </div>
    <div class="equipos" data-equipo="2">
        <img src="./img/telefono.png" alt="">
        <p>Plan Libre Plus</p>
    </div>
    <div class="equipos" data-equipo="3">
        <img src="./img/telefono.png" alt="">
        <p>Plan Libre Ultra</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui esta el js

```
var urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (urlSearchParams) {

var card = urlSearchParams.get('card')
var group = urlSearchParams.get('group')
var tab = urlSearchParams.get('tab')


var equipos = document.querySelector('#equipos');
var internet = document.querySelector('#internet');
var planes = document.querySelector('#planes');

switch(group){
    case 'equipos': {
        equipos.classList.add('active');
        if(equipos.classList.contains('active')){

            var $wrap = $('.container-equipos');
            $wrap.find('.equipos').sort(function(a, b){
               
                
                }
            }).appendTo($wrap);
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

esto es lo que tengo, pero nose como ordenarlos con sort, ya que sort me ordena del primero al ultimo o del ultimo al primero pero no el segundo.. gracias por ayuda

Comment: FIjate si en este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261473/invertir-orden-de-div) hay algo que te pueda ser de utilidad para lo que necesitas.